# React nested routes not loading components

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

for some reason this simple setup doesnt seem to work, what am i forgetting ?

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";


const Account = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            Account
        go back to <Link to="/menu">menu</Link>
        </div>
    )
}
const Book = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            Book
        go back to <Link to="/menu">menu</Link>
        </div>)
}
const Menu = props => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Route path="/menu" render={() => {
                return (
                    <div>
                        home
                        <br /><Link to="menu/account">account</Link>
                        <br /><Link to="menu/book">book</Link>
                    </div>
                )
            }} />
            <Route exact path="/menu/account" component={Account} />
            <Route exact path="/menu/book" component={Book} />
        </div>
    )
}


export default Menu;
```

theres a second issue on top of this one, in my bigger project the nested routes work but only when the route is called from the "Link tag" element, and breaks when called from refresh or adress bar (CSS goes crazy)

thank you.

Comment: You are missing a trailing `/` before link `<Link to="/menu/account">account</Link>` and `<Link to="/menu/book">book</Link>`

Comment: yes but it didnt really resolve it sadly.

Comment: Working demo of your code. https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-maxwell-s7c4n?file=/src/App.js

Maybe if you could show you use use Menu component and render other routes if would be helpful

Comment: this is driving me crazy, maybe theres something wrong with my browser. the code seems fine tough.

Comment: This should be a very minor issue. Does the url change when you click on `Link` . Also how do you render Menu component

Comment: sry its been forever, i managed to fix it thank you.

Comment: Glad it worked for you (y)